# Layer names for pretrained inception v3 model (tensorflow)

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

The task is to get per-layer output of a [pretrained cnn inceptionv3](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html) model.
For example I feed an image to this network, and I want to get not only its output, but output of each layer(layer-wise).

In order to do that, I have to know names of each layer output. It's quite easy to do for last and pre-last layer:

```
sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')
sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')
```

(names pool_3:0 and softmax:0 are listed in sources related to the model)

But what if I want to get output of not only last and pre-last layer, but also pre-pre-last, pre-pre-pre-last, etc, output of any layer of this model?

Then I have to know layer names. A similar question [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175174/extract-features-using-pre-trained-tensorflow-cnn)
 on stackoverflow, but there are only names for pre-last and last layers, which are also available in comments in the sources('pool_3:0', 'softmax:0')

The obvious way to get names is to draw a graph of the model. But it's not the case [because graph-drawing tool simply crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635131/unable-to-visualize-inception-v3-model-in-tensorboard-with-tensorflow-0-7-1).
Also there is an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1287) related to this.

I also tried:

1. To print all graph node names and construct graph using information only from node names. But node names are quite cryptic. Also connections between nodes are not so obvious, because of [inception v3 architecture](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567v3.pdf) So without knowing the connections between nodes, this approach is like to break the code of enigma :)
2. Then I tried to draw a graph of this model using own-written tool(get all inputs of given node(say, 'pool_3:0'), then get all inputs of each of inputs of 'pool_3:0', etc. This approach works for simple models. But when I tried to use it for inceptionv3 implementation from THE image recognition tutorial, I've got 16 GB of my RAM used, then 10 GB of swap, then I simply stopped looking under the hood. Maybe there are some cycles in graph(but how could it be if the network is feed-forward?)

So, maybe somebody who's participated in this pre-trained model implementation & 'shipping' is reading stackoverflow.

Or maybe somebody has already got layer-wise names for this model.
Please share it with me and ml community. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base question has already been asked (and answered) in [List of tensor names in graph in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336648/list-of-tensor-names-in-graph-in-tensorflow/)

To answer your concern with your approach (2) - that does work (i've done it). If I had to guess, you probably don't use a dictionary-like structure to store the nodes, so if multiple nodes get their input from the same node (like it happens a lot in the inception model), you insert that input node multiple times in your list of things to store / visit. If you take care to visit each node only once, that should run basically instantly without memory problems.

Comment: Actually, the pretrained inceptionv3 model shipped with tensorflow lacks the model.txt file. So I've asked about where I can download the model.txt in a comment to a question you've pointed me to. As for (2) - Yep! I really forgot about duplicate entries possibility. Your answer helped me a lot!