# How do I obtain the layer names for use in the iOS sample app? (Tensorflow)

Tags: ios, tensorflow

I'm very new to Tensorflow, and I'm trying to train something using the inception v3 network for use in an iPhone app. I managed to export my graph as a protocolbuffer file, manually remove the dropout nodes (correctly, I hope), and have placed that .pb file in my iOS project, but now I am receiving the following error:

```
Running model failed:Not found: FeedInputs: unable to find feed output input
```

which seems to indicate that my `input_layer_name` and `output_layer_name` variables in the iOS app are misconfigured.

I see in various places that it should be `Mul` and `softmax` respectively, for inception v3, but these values don't work for me.

My question is: what is a layer (with regards to this context), and how do I find out what mine are?

[This](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py) is the exact definition of the model that I trained, but I don't see "Mul" or "softmax" present.

[This](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.layers) is what I've been able to learn about layers, but it seems to be a different concept, since "Mul" isn't present in that list.

I'm worried that this might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740594/layer-names-for-pretrained-inception-v3-model-tensorflow) but "layers" aren't explained (are they tensors?) and `graph.get_operations()` *seems* to be deprecated, or maybe I'm using it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MohamedEzz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43436440/3086290) wrote there are no layers in Tensorflow graphs. There are only operations that can be placed under the same name scope.

Usually operations of a single layer placed under the same scope and applications that aware of name scope concept can display them grouped.

One of such applications is [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard). I believe that using Tensorboard is the easiest way to find node names.

Consider the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets as nets

input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 224, 224, 3))

network = nets.inception.inception_v3(input_placeholder)

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('.', tf.get_default_graph())

writer.close()
```

It creates placeholder for input data then creates Inception v3 network and saves event data (with graph) in current directory.

Launching Tensorflow in the same directory makes it possible to view graph structure.

```
tensorboard --logdir .
```

Tensorboard prints UI url to the console

```
Starting TensorBoard 41 on port 6006
(You can navigate to http://192.168.128.73:6006)
```

Below is an image of this graph.
[image]

Locate node you are interested in and select it to find its name (in the upper left information pane).

Input:
[image]
Output:
[image]

Please note that usually you need not node names but tensor names. In most cases it is enough to add `:0` to node name to get tensor name.

For example to run Inception v3 network created above using names from the graph use the following code (continuation of the above code):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(1, 224, 224, 3) # just random data
session = tf.InteractiveSession()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
result = session.run('InceptionV3/Predictions/Softmax:0', feed_dict={'Placeholder:0': data})
# result.shape = (1, 1000)
```

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer, and covers valuable points. Instead of using Tensorboard, I looped through and printed out every node in the graph to find the name, which ended up being something sort of like what you gave in the inference code you have at the end. Your answer also highlights the importance of placeholder nodes, which don't seem to exist in the Inception v3 model on github already, so I added my own and passed it in. I will take your answer as the accepted answer. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the core of tensorflow, there are ops (operations) and tensors (n-dimensional arrays). Each op takes tensors and gives back tensors. Layers are just convenience wrappers around a number of ops that represent a neural network layer.

For example a convolution layer is composed of mainly 3 ops :

1. conv2d op : this is what slides a kernel over the input tensor and does element-wise multiplication between the kernel and the underlying input window.
2. bias_add op : adds the biases to the tensor coming out of the conv2d op
3. activation op : applies an activation function element-wise to the output tensor of the bias_add op

To run a tensorflow model, you provide feeds (inputs) and fetches (desired outputs). These are tensors, or tensor names.

From this line of code [Inception_model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py#L329), it seems that what you need is a tensor named `'predictions'` which has the `n_class` output probabilities.

What you observed (`softmax`) is the type of the op that produced the `predictions` tensor

As for the input tensor name, the `inception_model.py` code does not show the input tensor name, since it's an argument to the function. So it depends on what name you have given to that input tensor.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your layers or variable add the parameter called name

```
with tf.name_scope("output"):
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_filters, num_classes], stddev=0.1), name="W2")
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_classes]), name="b2")
    scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(h_pool_flat, W2, b2, name="scores")
    pred_y = tf.nn.softmax(scores,name="pred_y")
```

In this case I can access final predicted values by using "output/pred_y". If you dont have name_scope, you can just use "pred_y" to get to the values

```
conv = tf.nn.conv1d(word_embeddedings,
                    W1,
                    stride=stride_size,
                    padding="VALID",
                    name="conv") #will have dimensions [batch_size,out_width,num_filters] out_width is a function of max_words,filter_size and stride_size
# Apply nonlinearity
h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b1), name="relu")
```

I called the layer "conv" and used it in the next layer. Paste your snippet like I have done here

Comment: I'm not sure I'm having issues accessing the outputs in my case, I think the app can't find the FeedInput named "input". I've added a `name` argument to my first Conv2d op and called it "image_input" and named the `input_layer_name` variable in the app to match, but it still can't find it.

Comment: Can you paste that bit of code. I am editing the answer to include conv layer

Comment: It's really just in the ios_camera example app, but I actually already got it to work. The answer that I was looking for is multi-faceted: the app is looking for the name of a placeholder tensor, and it is looking for the full name, which I found by looping through every node in the graph and printing each name. The full name ended up being tower_0/image_input:0 (after I created the placeholder Tensor with that name in the first place, of course). I can't believe it didn't already exist or wasn't named in the Inception model, this makes it difficult for beginners to extend.