# Get Fully Conected Layer of Mobilnet v1 Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Folks, I am using the tensorflow Mobilenet v1, and I retrained the last layer to output 4 classes, and it works. Now, I am trying to use the last fully connected layer (or last feature layter instead of the softmax layer) to then feed this into an LSTM network. I just don't know which is the last layer I need from mobilenet v1. Here is the model I am using: [mobilenet_v1](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_1.0_128_2017_06_14.tar.gz)
Here is the code I used to see all layers, yet I don't know which one to pick:

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph = tf.Graph()
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
model_file = '/home/root/model/output_graph.pb'
with open(model_file, "rb") as f:
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
with graph.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
print(graph.get_operations())
```

Comment: You can visualize your graph in TensorBoard and lookup tensor name there. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493222/3086290) for more details.

Comment: I did. I just did not know which tensor to use

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the last Bottleneck layer right before the Software is what I need to use. That layer returns a 1x1001 matrix